# Unable to hide/disable Config file from sitecore

Tags: configuration

[image]I want disable couple of config files using patch file or edit layer.config file.Have included below peace of lines of code to disable file.

I can disable specific config by adding .disable/example to config but i dont want to each and every config to disable. am looking for single patch config file to disable config.

```
<add path="Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Solr.Index.Master.config" type="File" mode="Off" />
<add path="Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Solr.Index.Web.config" type="File" mode="Off" />
```

Eventually above piece code not working , could some suggest how i can disable config files.

Comment: are the above lines wrapped in a `<loadOrder>` section?

Comment: <layer name="MarketingAssets" includeFolder="/App_Config/Sitecore/Marketing.Assets/">
    <loadOrder>
 <add path="Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Solr.Index.Master.config" type="File" mode="Off" />
 <add path="Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Solr.Index.Web.config" type="File" mode="Off" />
 </loadOrder>
  </layer>
Yes, its wrapped with load order.

Comment: any chance it's case-sensitive? as in `mode="off"` instead of `mode="Off"`?

Comment: can you please tell what's your Sitecore version

Comment: Using 9.x only ...I tired with both mode="off" and mode="Off".. it didnt work out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature won't support on `Sitecore 9.x` version and this feature will be supported on `Sitecore 10.x` version only. If you would like to use this feature please upgrade `Sitecore 10.X`.

I had raised a Sitecore support ticket and they confirmed this product bug on `Sitecore 9.x` version. For more information please find below the Sitecore support `Ticket case number (CS0300419).`

Answer (score 0):

To disable a single patch file, you can do one of two things:

**Option1:** Navigate to the patch file in the file system, and rename it to end in something other than .config. For example, rename `Sitecore.Analytics.Config to Sitecore.Analytics.Config.Disabled`.

**Option2**: Add the patch file to a `<loadOrder> section and add the` mode="Off"` attribute.
For example:
`<add path="Sitecore.Analytics.Config" type="File" mode="Off" />`

**Note**: Option 2 will only work with 9.0 or later versions.

Comment: I am looking for second option but that is not working .Am able to hide folder level by adding mode="off" but its not working on config level.

Comment: Yes .. am using Sitecore version 9.x only

Comment: did you wrap it into <loadOrder>

Comment: yes. Wrapped with loadorder
 <layer name="MarketingAssets" includeFolder="/App_Config/Sitecore/Marketing.Assets/">
    <loadOrder>
 <add path="Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Solr.Index.Master.config" type="File" mode="Off" />
 <add path="Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Solr.Index.Web.config" type="File" mode="Off" />
 </loadOrder>
  </layer>

Comment: i tried like this also in layer.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layers>
  <layer name="Sitecore" includeFolder="/App_Config/Sitecore/">
    <loadOrder>
 <add path="FederatedExperienceManager/Sitecore.FXM.Solr.DomainsSearch.Index.Master.config" type="File" mode="off"/>
</loadOrder>
 
  </layer>
  </layers>
but none of things didnt workout

Comment: type will be file here <add path="FederatedExperienceManager/Sitecore.FXM.Solr.DomainsSearch.Index.Master.config" type="File" mode="off"/>

Comment: sorry ..i used type="File" only  but above comment i typed wrongly.

Comment: can you please add screenshot of path config file

Comment: added screen shot

Comment: ...any your inputs here

Comment: if not working yet please try to add directly into Layers.config

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to double-check the path and placement of your `config` into the `Layers.config` file. Look at the below example.

I need to disable a config file named `training.config`. And this is in the folder `\App_Config\Include\zzz`.

So I added the location and the path in the `Layers.config` file like this.

```
<layer name="Custom" includeFolder="/App_Config/Include/">
   <loadOrder>
      <add path="Foundation" type="Folder" />
      <add path="Feature" type="Folder" />
      <add path="Project" type="Folder" />
      <add path="/zzz/training.config" type="File" mode="off" />
   </loadOrder>
```

So you can see that I used the location under the include folder i.e. `/App_Config/Include/` and then given the path of the file under the `zzz` folder like this `/zzz/training.config`

And this is working for me.

Please check and verify the path and the location where you are adding in the `Layers.config` and try again.

Also for your config that you have mentioned in your question, I have checked and it's working fine on my local and I have added the entry in the `Layers.config` file like this.

```
<loadOrder>
  <add path="/Marketing.Assets/Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Solr.Index.Master.config" type="File" mode="off" />
  <add path="/Marketing.Assets/Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.MarketingAssets.Repositories.Solr.Index.Web.config" type="File" mode="off" />
```

Adding the screenshot of `Layers.Config`.

[image]

Hope this will solve your issue.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for you details explanation.. had tried same approach for me its was not workout

Comment: @Reddy did you add `/Marketing.Assets/` before your config in the path. As I have shared?

Comment: Yes ...Can u please share your screen shoot of your layer.config

Comment: @Reddy I have updated my answer with screenshot.

Comment: Under which Layer you have included below above two patches...  Layer means Sitecore or Module 0r custom?

Comment: @Reddy It is mentioned in the screenshot. Under `Sitecore`

Comment: I have changed Layer.config as per your screen shot..still issues not resolved for me ...am using sitecore version 9.0.1 and may i know your sitecore version?

Comment: This is for Sitecore 10.1 @Reddy

Comment: @ Sumit..this feature will  work on sitecore 9.0.1 correct ?

Comment: @Reddy Yes it will

Comment: but its not working fine for me on sitecore 9.0.1

Comment: @Reddy I will suggest you add a custom config and check with that. If that doesn't work then the issue is with your solution.

Comment: Based on my knowledge layer.config is not sitecore file its not possible to add custom patch..what you mean custom config and give some example here .
If its problem with my solution it should not work folder level exclusion but its working fine on folder level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136724/discussion-between-sumit-bhatia-and-reddy).